# [WSO2][EI Analitics] How to do complex searches on Analytics Dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

[EI 6.1.0] I have an HL7 proxy that send statistic to EI Analitics. I can do simple research on HL7 messages using the analitics dashboard.
Es. *afterPayload: searchTerm*
[image]

My questions are:

1. how to do complex searches on multiple terms and what is the syntax to use?
2. Because if I add a value to a response(modifying HL7 or adding a context property) this value is not searchable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what pattern your complex search would be? If you searching multiple attribute in JSON body, you can do lucence indexing in the event store and in the UI you can implement search JSON body values by separating values by space.
Ex: wordone wordtwo

Comment: Thanks for reply. For complex search I mean search on multiple words. My payload is in HL7. My doubt is about how to do lucene indexing in event stores for new data added with enrich mediator?